# Stuck on SOMA level

Tags: soma

I'm playing SOMA, and I'm around 2-3 hours into the game. The guides for some reason don't seem to make sense, they talk about events I haven't passed and I'm not sure where this part is covered, I'm not sure if I've skipped something.

I'm supposed to find an escape vehicle or something, not exactly sure what. But there's a... *thing* in the region that keeps killing me, I've tried to outrun it and find an exit, but there doesn't appear to be one. Not sure what I'm supposed to do.

[image: SOMA area]
[image: SOMA enemy]

Comment: Just run down the ladder. Then go through that central room, somwhere in hallway you will find a room with escape pod. Press button to close the door and leave. I did automatically so don't remember details.

Comment: When you get to the pod you will be told to switch off the power on the CURIE so you have to go back to do so. After that there will be a funny scene involving you running from the bastard and barely escaping from the guy so in fact you won't push any buttons on the pod since it will be part of a cutscene.

Comment: I had to resort to using the video walkthroughs to get out of a couple places as all the written ones didn't match up with what had actually happened.

Answer (score 3):

If you listen to the hints you can figure out that you **must not** look at this guy. He is not too fast but if you see him just look away and try to keep the distance from him. The sounds will help.

I don't want to spoil the fun for you but I believe that Catherine tells you that the shuttle is blocked by CURIE for some reason so you have to turn the power off on the ship.

It is really not that hard to find. Again I don't want to spoil the fun but if you find the room where the reactor is you have to do something...witty. You don't have to do anything anywhere else. I don't remember right exactly but I think you also have to pull some lever to be able to reach the escape shuttle. So in general:

- Find a way (I think it was a lever somewhere) to get to the shuttle
- Once you get in there you will be told to switch off power on CURIE
- Look for the generator room and switch off power there
- and **never look at the guy**

Comment: I was going to ask this as a separate question, but maybe it's just worth asking here. Does this guy actively pursue you if you aren't looking/hiding? It seems like he just gets really close if he sees you, but as long as you aren't in his way or looking at him, he kind of just forgets about you and walk away.

Comment: I believe that if you move but don't look at him he teleports to fixed points on the ship as you move. To which point he teleports depends on where you are: he always teleports to the closest point to you. If you look at him he starts to use a new strategy: he teleports closer and closer to you until you die. He is scripted though because there are some rooms where he is not present and there is an event after which he starts to teleport closer to you regardless of your facing.

Comment: So after a given point he does actively try to hunt you?

Comment: I don't want to spoil the fun. See it for yourself :)

Comment: I believe Catherine says that the escape pod won't activate because the Curie doesn't realize there's been an emergency. She tells you to do whatever you can to convince the ship otherwise, i.e. [sabotage](https://youtu.be/z5rRZdiu1UE).